# Is it possible to force the use of a type from a discriminated union in another type?

Tags: f#, discriminated-union

An example:

```
type A = 
    | Type1 of string
    | Type2 of string
```

and then a type where:

```
type B =
    {
        SomeField : bool
        MyData : A.Type1
    }
```

Is something like this possible?

Here's the problem I am trying to solve:
I have objects with 2 possible Ids (one self assigned and one assigned by a 3rd party). In practice, they're string guids.
In the main object, both Ids are represented:

```
{
    AssignedId: string
    InternalId: string
}
```

but then some APIs take a list of Ids as a list of string, so both types can be used. Later on, some API calls will be different depending if the Id is the assigned one, or the internal one. This means that Ids of both types get mixed in lists, and then later on I need to split them by type to properly route the calls. The Ids are used interchangeably through the system, depending on the context.

Right now, there is a special character in front of the internal Id, but I was hoping to clean this up and use a type.

What I have in mind is to define an id DU that can represent both the 3rd party id and the internal one, use that in the pipeline and parse the type only when needed. The only difficulty is that in the main object itself, I need to be able to tell: this field holds the 3rd party id, and that field holds the internal id.

Comment: Just trying to understand your requirement. You need a way to represent both types of id's together (I assume for matching both systems), and you need a way to represent each type of ID individually and what type of ID it is, and you need to be able to create a sequence or list where each item can be either type of ID, but not both at the same time. Does that sum it up?

Comment: (btw, using a single case of a discriminated union as if it's a type is not possible, but I think your use case is nonetheless very well expressable, if it is what I think it is)

Comment: yes; essentially there are objects with both ids and they need to be separated there; then any of these two id types can be sent in the pipeline, processed identically, etc and then at the end they need to be matched again. right now they're strings with a marker, so they are used interchangeably and then sorted in the end process

Comment: What you're looking for is the "Either" pattern. Gimme a moment, I'll write something up

Comment: one point that may make a difference is that the object always has the 3rd party id present; and sometimes an internal one as well, but not always. depending on the use case one id, or the other one will be used during processing. It's financial transactions that always come with an id and some of them we don't want to wait for the official id so we set our own (the official one will eventually arrive). but final transactions use a different api if it's our id or the official one, while the middle pipeline can use both.

Comment: About that last comment: you may want to have the `InternalId` on the record then set to `option`. If the official id and assigned id can differ because you give a tentative id, I'd suggest you add a property, like a bool, like `type AssignedGuid = AssignedGuid of bool * Guid`, if all other things are equal, where the bool means whether it is tentative or not.

Answer (score 0):

This may get you going in the right direction. Only now just saw your last comment, which may suggest that the record type should have the `InternalId` set to `InternalGuid option` instead.

I think this is self explanatory, I added comments and a few tests. But feel free to comment if something is unclear. The code is untested, though, but I think you'll get the gist ;).

Note: the option-extension is just a little handy function I use a lot, and since you said you were working with guids, I figured I added it.

```
module Option =
    let ofByRef(success, v) = if success then Some v else None

// two wrapper types for type safety and preventing misuse, and is needed for the Record type
type InternalGuid = InternalGuid of Guid
type AssignedGuid = AssignedGuid of Guid

/// This type can be either Assigned or Internal
type EitherId =
    | InternalId of InternalGuid
    | AssignedId of AssignedGuid

    static member internal tryParseGuid (prefix: string) (str: string) =
        if str.StartsWith prefix then 
            str.Substring 1
            |> Guid.TryParse 
            |> Option.ofByRef
        else
            None

    static member makeInternal guid = InternalGuid guid |> InternalId
    static member makeAssigned guid = AssignedGuid guid |> AssignedId

    static member isInternal = function InternalId _ -> true | _ -> false
    static member isAssigned = function AssignedId _ -> true | _ -> false

    // you can check for the leading extra char here
    static member tryParseInternal (str: string) =
        EitherId.tryParseGuid "I" str
        |> Option.map (InternalGuid >> InternalId)

    // you can check for the leading extra char here
    static member tryParseAssignedId (str: string) = 
        EitherId.tryParseGuid "A" str
        |> Option.map (AssignedGuid >> AssignedId)

    /// create either an InternalId or AssignedId based on prefix
    static member tryParse str =
        EitherId.tryParseInternal str
        |> Option.orElseWith (fun _ -> EitherId.tryParseInternal str)

/// This type maps the Internal ID to the Assigned ID
type CombinedId =
    {
        InternalId: InternalGuid
        AssignedId: AssignedGuid
    }

module Tests =

    let mixedList = [EitherId.makeInternal(Guid.NewGuid()); EitherId.makeAssigned(Guid.NewGuid())]

    // list with only internal ids
    let mapInternalOnly =
        mixedList
        |> List.filter EitherId.isInternal

    // list with only assigned ids
    let mapAssignedOnly =
        mixedList
        |> List.filter EitherId.isAssigned
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this today and report